# Cakephp Ajax call works in localhost but not in server, request-data changing to null after 1 seconds but works fine on localhost

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp, localhost

I have a very strange problem here:

**In my index.ctp, I have the following code that makes ajax request to the server**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo Router::url(array('controller' => 'brands', 'action'  =>'filters'), true); ?>",
    cache: false,
    data    : "Mod=weaves",
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'Html',
    success: function (data) {
       $('#resultsall').html(data);
    }           
})
```

**in my Brand controller's filters action, I have this**

```
public function filters(){
    if ($this->request->is('ajax')) {
       $this->Brand->recursive = 0;
       echo debug($this->request->data);
       if($this->Session->read('conditions.brand')){
           $brandconditions = $this->Session->read('conditions.brand');
           $this->Paginator->settings = array('fields' => array('name', 'id'), 
                                              'conditions' => array('Brand.id' => $brandconditions)) + 
           $this->Paginator->settings;
           $this->set('brands', $this->Paginator->paginate());
       }
       $this->set('mode', $this->request->data['Mod']);
       $this->render('results','ajax');
    }
}
```

I kept on getting undefined index Mod. when run on server but works well on my localhost.
If I run echo debug on localhost, I get expected result but on server, the request-data shows up correctly for 1 seconds, then the array becomes null after one seconds.

Comment: what is this data?data    : "Mod=weaves" ? maybe it is not passed corrected to the filters.

Answer (score 0):

I think data should be passed as:

```
data: {"Mod" : "weaves"}
```